# Get Excel cell background color in pandas read_excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an `.xls` Excel file with cells having background colors. I am reading that file into *pandas* with `read_excel`. Is there any way to get the background colors of cells?

Comment: You may want to consider dropping down into [`xlrd`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) (which Pandas uses) to get the colour information.

Comment: Will try and get back here if I get lucky!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Brute-forced it through [`xlrd`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd), as per [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson)'s suggestion:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
wb = open_workbook('wb.xls', formatting_info=True)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name("mysheet")
#create empy colormask matrix
bgcol=np.zeros([sheet.nrows,sheet.ncols])
#cycle through all cells to get colors
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
  for column in range(sheet.ncols):
    cell = sheet.cell(row, column)  
    fmt = wb.xf_list[cell.xf_index]
    bgcol[row,column]=fmt.background.background_colour_index
#return pandas mask of colors
colormask=pd.DataFrame(bgcol)
```

Yet, there must be a better way thorugh pandas directly...

Comment: Unfortunately formatting_info=True only works on .xls but not on .xlsx files :-(  A good hint anyway - thnks!

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work properly for me with xls either. I have several background colours and the matrix results in all cells having colour index 64..

Comment: @JoePhi Please look at my solution below. It works for XLSX file. It gives the color code, both in Hex and RGB tuple.

Answer (score 15):

The Solution suggested above works only for `xls` file, not for `xlsx` file. This raises a `NotImplementedError: formatting_info=True not yet implemented`. `Xlrd` library is still not updated to work for `xlsx` files. So you have to `Save As` and change the format every time which may not work for you. 
 
Here is a solution for `xlsx` files using `openpyxl` library. `A2` is the cell whose color code we need to find out.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
excel_file = 'color_codes.xlsx' 
wb = load_workbook(excel_file, data_only = True)
sh = wb['Sheet1']
color_in_hex = sh['A2'].fill.start_color.index # this gives you Hexadecimal value of the color
print ('HEX =',color_in_hex) 
print('RGB =', tuple(int(color_in_hex[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))) # Color in RGB
```

Comment: In my case this approach was giving inaccurate results (i.e. not capturing colors correctly).

Comment: I checked it for my project, it worked just fine. Can you share your example ?

Comment: Unfortunately excel has multiple ways of colouring in cells. This only finds one of them.

Comment: This was useful https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html?highlight=start_color -- for understanding non-hex (indexed) results which were labeled in this link as legacy support.

Answer (score 5):

Improving on [Sumit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61343287/3284713) (which should be the accepted one in my opinion), you can obtain the color for the whole column by using list comprehension:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
excel_file = 'my_file.xlsx' 
wb = load_workbook(excel_file, data_only = True)
sh = wb['my_sheet']
# extract color from column A.
color_in_hex = [cell.fill.start_color.index for cell in sh['A:A']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited the code snippet from @csaladenes's response above based on [this link](https://python-forum.io/Thread-How-to-obtain-the-background-color-of-a-cell-using-xlrd), and it works for my xls file (the original resulted in all cells showing the same color index, though they have different background colors):

```
import xlrd
import numpy as np
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file, formatting_info=True)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name("mysheet")
bgcol=np.zeros([sheet.nrows,sheet.ncols])
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    for col in range(sheet.ncols):
        c = sheet.cell(row, col)
        cif = sheet.cell_xf_index(row, col)
        iif = wb.xf_list[cif]
        cbg = iif.background.pattern_colour_index
        bgcol[row,col] = cbg
```