# python pandas detect color in cell and add as new column

Tags: python, pandas, etl

I have a xlsx file with color in cells and I would like to detect the color of each cell and add it as a new column. Result:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this using the pandas library in Python? if not, is there any library to get the colors?

Greetings

Comment: are you asking if in pandas we can convert #FFFF00 into the name of the color ?

Comment: @mohanys nope, I would like detect the color in the first column and then add it as a new column with the name of it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identifying Excel Sheet cell color code using XLRD package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991209/identifying-excel-sheet-cell-color-code-using-xlrd-package)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Excel cell background color in pandas read\_excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857112/get-excel-cell-background-color-in-pandas-read-excel)