# How to detect color of excel(.xlsx) row

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, openpyxl

[image]

I want to detect background color of each cell the output can be HEX value or RGB. I have the above dataframe stored.

Comment: Not going to happen with pandas. Perhaps openpyxl.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61343287/6389787

Comment: You should always include your own code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) Python library to parse an Excel document, iterate over its cells, and check the cell value, style, color, etc.

If the fill background or foreground color is other than the string value "00000000" then it uses a custom color. A Red fill color would have an ARGB value of FFFF0000.

**Example:**

```python
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/path/file.xlsx', data_only=True)

# get first worksheet
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

# check first column in first 10 rows for fill color
for row in range(1, 10):
    cell = ws.cell(column=1, row=row)
    bgColor = cell.fill.bgColor.index
    fgColor = cell.fill.fgColor.index
    if bgColor != '00000000' or fgColor != '00000000':
        print(f"row {row}")
        print(f"  fgColor={fgColor}")
        print(f"  bgColor={bgColor}")
        print(f"  fillType={cell.fill.fill_type}")
        print(f"  value: {cell.value}")
```

To set a color to a cell, use [PatternFill](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.styles.fills.html)

```
cell.fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor="5cb800")
```