# Python Code Excel Cell Color Check is not working

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2EJU.png)

```
import openpyxl

def sum_gr_values(file_name):
    # Load the workbook
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
    sheet = workbook.active

    # Find the first yellow-filled cell
    yellow_cell = None
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.fill.start_color.rgb == '#FFFF00':
                yellow_cell = cell
                break
        if yellow_cell:
            break

    # Set the start and end row variables
    start_row = yellow_cell
    end_row = start_row

    # Find the last yellow-filled cell
    for row in range(start_row + 1, sheet.max_row + 1):
        if sheet.cell(row=row, column=yellow_cell.column).fill.start_color.index == 'FFFF00':
            end_row = row
        else:
            break

    # Check if start_row and end_row have values
    if start_row and end_row:
        # Initialize a variable to store the sum
        total_sum = 0

        # Sum the values in column "E" if the value in column "F" is "GR"
        for row in range(start_row, end_row + 1):
            if sheet.cell(row=row, column=6).value == "GR":
                total_sum += sheet.cell(row=row, column=5).value

        # Write the sum to the first yellow-filled cell in column "E"
        yellow_cell.offset(0, -1).value = total_sum

    # Save the changes to the file
    workbook.save(file_name)
file_name = "file.xlsx"
sum_gr_values(file_name)
```

In the "# Find the first yellow-filled cell" section yellow cell is not dedected. I've also add the excel screnshot. Tried to debug but could not understand problem. I am new in coding so it might be an easy one.

It needs to detect the yellow rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **openpyxl** Python library to parse an Excel document, iterate over its cells, and check the cell value, style, color, etc.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69410376/how-to-detect-color-of-excel-xlsx-row[enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69410376/how-to-detect-color-of-excel-xlsx-row%5Benter) link description here][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69410376/how-to-detect-color-of-excel-xlsx-row)

Answer (score 0):

Check the last 6 characters
`if cell.fill.start_color.rgb[-6:] == 'FFFF00':`

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

def sum_gr_values(file_name):

    # list of yellow cells
    cellY = []
    
    # Load the workbook
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
    sheet = workbook.active

    # Find the yellow-filled rows
    for r in sheet.iter_rows():
        if r[0].fill.start_color.rgb[-6:] == 'FFFF00':
            cellY.append(r[0])
    
    #append last row
    cellY.append(r[0].offset(1))
    
    # check results    
    for n in range(0,len(cellY)):
        print( "n: {} rowY: {}".format(n,cellY[n].row) ) 
    print()
    
    ## Check have 2 rows  
    if len(cellY) < 2:
        print ( "ERROR - No yellow rows found" )
        exit()
    
    # summate each pair of yellow lines
    for n in range(0,len(cellY)-1):
        # Initialize a variable to store the sum
        total_sum = 0
        r0 = cellY[n].row # start row
        r1 = cellY[n+1].row # end row
        print ( "n={} r0={} r1={}".format(n,r0,r1) )

        ## Sum the values in column "E" if the value in column "F" is "GR"
        for rowno in range(r0+1, r1):
            colE = sheet.cell(rowno, 5).value
            colF = sheet.cell(rowno, 6).value      
            print (rowno,colE, colF)
            if  colF == "GR":
                total_sum += colE

        ## Write the sum to the first yellow-filled cell in column "E"
        sheet.cell(r0, 5).value = total_sum
        sheet.cell(r0, 5).fill = PatternFill(start_color="FFFF00", fill_type = "solid")
        print ( "total:{}\n".format(total_sum) )


    # Save the changes to the file
    workbook.save(file_name)

# program
file_name = "file.xlsx"
sum_gr_values(file_name)
```