# How I can add a specific comment in excel with pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

This is the dataframe:

[image: Dataframe]

I want at the column `endingBalanceLC` to add a comment just in the yellow cell. The problem is that I don't know exactly where this account and the aferent total are in my dataframe because the position can always change,depends the excel. The comment which I want to add is "this is a balance amount".

I was thinking to use `xlsxwriter` but I don't know how.

Comment: I would recommend using the `openpxyl` library as background color can be read in from `.xlsx` files as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61343287/5327068). This library also supports [adding comments](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/comments.html). When I have a moment, I would be happy to add answer if no one else has done so

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can use `openpyxl` to read in a file, detect cell(s) with a certain background color, and add a comment to these cells.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.comments import Comment

excel_file = 'sample.xlsx' 
wb = load_workbook(excel_file, data_only = True)
sh = wb['Sheet1']

# iterate through excel and display data
for i in range(1, sh.max_row+1):
    for j in range(1, sh.max_column+1):
        ## check if the background is yellow
        if sh.cell(row=i, column=j).fill.start_color.index == 'FFFFFF00':
            sh.cell(row=i, column=j).comment = Comment("This is a balance account", "author name")

wb.save('commented_sample.xlsx')
```

You can either overwrite the original file, or create a new xlsx file which will look like this:

[image: description]