# In Python, how to read and count all values from an Exceel sheet only if the cell has no color?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have multiple exceel sheets that I am not able to change structure of. Each sheet contains multiple tables of different structures so it's hard to automatically parse it. However, the cells of interest are white cells in all these tables, all other cells such as headers and extra meta data has colored cells.

So, is there a way to extract all cells from an exceel sheet fulfilling the condition of having the color white and count the occurence of each value?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857112/get-excel-cell-background-color-in-pandas-read-excel) shows some ways of getting a cell's background color, maybe you can adapt this for your needs?

Comment: Share a sample file (Google drive, onebox, ...) With expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question lacks specifics but here is a *good start* with some help from [openpyxl](/questions/tagged/openpyxl) :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

data = [
    [cell.value if cell.fill.start_color.rgb == "00000000" else None for cell in row]
    for row in load_workbook("input_file.xlsx")["Sheet1"].iter_rows(min_row=1)
    if any(cell.fill.start_color.rgb == "00000000" for cell in row)
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data) # add `columns=["A", ..]` to specify a custom header
```

Output :

```
print(df)

      0  1
0   foo  1
1  None  2
2   qux  3
3   baz  4
```

*Spreadsheet used :*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use openyxl library:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

#Create a function
def count_cells_with_color(file_path, color):
    workbook = load_workbook(filename=file_path)
    sheet = workbook.active

    white_cells = []
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.fill.fgColor.rgb == color:
                white_cells.append(cell.value)

    cell_counts = {}
    for cell_value in white_cells:
        if cell_value not in cell_counts:
            cell_counts[cell_value] = 1
        else:
            cell_counts[cell_value] += 1

    return cell_counts

file_path = 'path/to/your/excel/file.xlsx'
white_color = 'FFFFFFFF'  # RGB value for white

cell_counts = count_cells_with_color(file_path, white_color)
print(cell_counts)
```

I hope this help.